# How to say "Please save his portion for him to eat later" more natively and shortly?

Tags: vocabulary, spoken-english, food

Say one friend is absent at the time when we are eating out with friends. And maybe also the food is so great that we just couldn't stop eating more than we need.

So, if I want to remind/tell my friends that are present at the moment, to leave his portion alone so that s/he can eat it when later when he comes to the event etc, how do I convey the message in just few words and more natively?

I tried googling things like "Save his portion", "Leave his portion of food", "Don't eat his food portion" etc but couldn't find some result which proves that such usage exists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding what you're saying.  If I am eating out with friends we each have our own food, our portions as you say.  What food is for your absent friend?  Did someone place an order (order a portion) for the absent friend?  Is his plate sitting on the table getting cold in his absence?  Or do you mean that you want to save some of the food that you ordered as group to take to the absent friend?

Answer (score 3):

If you're saving a portion of food from a meal for someone, it's obviously for them to consume later; no need to mention it. And @Coco's answer is the simplest and clearest:

- *Save some for* <`name`>

is really all you need. If `name` is masculine, and already relevant in context, then *him* can be used.

All the rest is implied in the context of a shared meal. *Save* has a special meaning of 'preserve in edible form' in this context, and *some* clearly refers to 'some portion of the food that is being eaten'.

Answer (score 0):

There are no magic words.

There is not special combination of words that you must use. This is part of a conversation, so you would expect several people to be talking. If you say something it is understood in context and if not the other people have the opportunity to respond and ask questions.

So something like

> Hey guys, don't forget Mike.
>
> What about him?
>
> Well, leave something for when he gets back.

You will notice that I didn't mention "food" at all! It is all in the context.

You will also notice that I explicitly included what the other person said.  Of course they might say something else, and you could respond to that.

A conversation is always a two way process.  Never forget the other person.